# Element locked on scroll pure JavaScript no Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, parallax

[image]I am trying to lock the green box to the very top of the when a user scrolls through the content. However, when you scroll there is a gap on top of the green box (as shown in the demonstration)

I've tried to set position to fixed for the green box, but it jumps out of the red box. So it needs to remain absolute.

Please look at the example I've set it up live here http://jsfiddle.net/jpXjH/839/

OR look at the code here

```
<div style="padding: 20px 0px; background-color:cyan;">
    This is a header with some random content
</div>

  <div style="width:480px; height:1400px; overflow:hidden; margin:auto; 
   border:1px solid gray; position:relative; background-color: #ff5d5d; ">

      <div id="locked">
         This element needs to be on the very top LOCKED when scrolled down. 
         However you can see there is a gap in the very top when you scroll.
      </div>

</div>

<style>
#locked{
    background-color: limegreen;
    padding:10px;
    width:150px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
</style>
<script>
    window.onscroll = changePos;

            function changePos() {
                var locked = document.getElementById("locked");

                if (window.pageYOffset > 30) {
                    locked.style.position = "absolute";
        locked.style.float = "right";
                    locked.style.top = pageYOffset + "px"
                } else {
                    locked.style.position = "";
                    locked.style.top = "";
                }
            }
<script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: is this what you want to achieve? not sure if i understand your question right http://jsfiddle.net/jpXjH/843/

Comment: That is exactly it Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution I can think of is to subtract the height of the locked bar at the top from the header.style.top you alter in your JS:

```
header.style.top = pageYOffset - 76 + "px"
```

obviously you can get the height directly from the element instead of hardcoding it.

Comment: Brilliant, very simple and clean

Answer (score 0):

Your body or html tag probably has some padding/margin on it. Check if it does, and then account for it by substracting the amount from the window.pageYOffset global.

You also need to account for the height of any element that comes before the red div.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't try to use position fixed, like:

```
#header{
  background-color: limegreen;
  padding:10px;
  width:150px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}

    window.onscroll = changePos;

                function changePos() {
                    var header = document.getElementById("header");

                    if (window.pageYOffset > 30) {
                        //header.style.position = "absolute";
            header.style.float = "right";
                        //header.style.top = pageYOffset + "px"
                    } else {
                        header.style.position = "";
                        header.style.top = "";
                    }
                }
```

And if you and to be aligned with red container you can calculate with JS.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the green box needs to be inside the red one. hence cant use fixed

Comment: Yes, but I tell you, use jquery or what you like to calculate red and green boxes to have same margin-right. It's easy, right?